# angular-imgcache.js image path issue iOS only

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, caching, ionic-framework

For a few days I have been trying to resolve this issue. The angular-imgcache.js module works in Android but not in iOS. I can inspect the filesystem on both Android and the app container on iOS. The difference is imgcache directory is in the root of the file system on Android while iOS the imgcache is under `Library/files/imgcache`. Below are the messages I see in the safari remote inspector when I refresh.

```
[Log] INFO: LocalFileSystem opened (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] INFO: Local cache folder opened: /imgcache/ (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] INFO: com.apple.MobileBackup metadata set (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] ERROR: Download error source: https://URLPATH (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] ERROR: Download error target: cdvfile://localhost/root/imgcache/c56f69853d5444c697307b96a1eef89a55a64830.jpg (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] ERROR: Download error code: 1 (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] ERROR: Download error source: https://URLPATH (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] ERROR: Download error target: cdvfile://localhost/root/imgcache/be0f1e88a316eb2b049b2bc09fadef9cac2c5e87.jpg (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] ERROR: Download error code: 1 (vendors.min.js, line 852)
```

After the initial load I can override the imagecache directory used in the filecache operation by modifying this object

```
ImgCache.attributes.dirEntry
Object
filesystem: Object
fullPath: "/imgcache/"
isDirectory: true
isFile: false
name: "imgcache"
nativeURL: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CONTAINER_HASH/Library/files/imgcache/"
__proto__: Object


> ImgCache.attributes.dirEntry.fullPath = ImgCache.attributes.dirEntry.nativeURL
< "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CONTAINER_HASH/Library/files/imgcache/"
> ImgCache.cacheFile("https://URLPATH");
< undefined
[Log] INFO: Download complete: /imgcache/c56f69853d5444c697307b96a1eef89a55a64830.jpg (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] INFO: Cached file size: 14122 (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] INFO: current size: 14122 (vendors.min.js, line 852)
[Log] INFO: com.apple.MobileBackup metadata set (vendors.min.js, line 852)
```

I have tried setting the ImgCache in this manner prior to initialization but that ends up causing initialization errors. Either there is something wrong with my implementation or this ImgCache has a bug on iOS. Here is a bit of my configuration.

```
  //ImgCache.attributes.dirEntry.fullPath = ImgCache.attributes.filesystem.root.nativeURL;
  //ImgCacheProvider.setOption('debug', true);
  //imgCache options
  // set single options
  ImgCacheProvider.setOption('debug', true);
  ImgCacheProvider.setOption('usePersistentCache', true);

  // or more options at once
  ImgCacheProvider.setOptions({
      debug: true,
      usePersistentCache: true
  });

  // ImgCache library is initialized automatically,
  // but set this option if you are using platform like Ionic -
  // in this case we need init imgcache.js manually after device is ready
  ImgCacheProvider.manualInit = true;
```

The initialization occurs inside the `$ionicPlatform.ready`

```
  // PhoneGap application
  if (navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      console.log('$ionicPlatform');
      Analytics.init();

      if (phoneCheck.android) {
        ionic.Platform.isFullScreen = true;
      }
      if (phoneCheck.ios) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          navigator.splashscreen.hide();
          ImgCache.$init();
        }, 2500);
      }
    });
  }
```